# Same page link not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, markdown, footnotes

I have written my own blog let’s say at example.com.
I’ m trying to use footnotes for my posts. 
So I have a post at the address:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/2012/04/post-slug
```

I use this code for the footnotes (produced by markdown-extra):

```
<p>That's some text with a footnote.<sup id="fnref:1"><a href="#fn:1" rel="footnote">1</a></sup></p>

<div class="footnotes">
<hr />
<ol>
<li id="fn:1">
<p>And that's the footnote.&#160;<a href="#fnref:1" rev="footnote">&#8617;</a></p>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

This code is saved in the database as the post’s body.

The problem is that when I point to the browser to the post and click the links they point  to the home page of my site like this:

```
http://www.example.com/#fnref:1
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/#fn:1
```

Instead of the correct:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/2012/04/post-slug#fnref:1
```

And

```
http://www.example.com/blog/2012/04/post-slug#fn:1
```

respectively.

That is they don’t take in mind the part of the URL

```
/blog/2012/04/post-slug
```

They "think" they are in the home page for some reason.
In Codeigniter I have chosen not to include index.php in the URL. And of course I have some routing definition in the routes.php file.
I cant’ figure out why this problem occurs. Maybe it has to do with routing.
I have tried all the available options in the config.php file:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] =  'AUTO';
```

(PATH_INFO etc) but didn’t help.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `<base href="" />` defined in your `<head>`? This will override anchors.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Thank you very much! I guess I'll have to choose between <base href=""/> and anchors.

Comment: You can probably hack your way around that with some nifty JavaScript, but things usually work better without a <base>. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

CI always behaves as it's in the root this because that's where its index.php file is located and all the controllers/methods are called from there.
To solve your case, I'd suggest you add a path to your `href` attribute, or use `base`, like Zenbait said.

Comment: I guess that if I continue using 'base href' I must add the correct path to my anchors manually or alter the markdown library to add the path to the anchor.

Comment: Yeah, avoiding `base` is a better idea.